# Error in Makefile: gcc: error: filename.o :No such file or directory found

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have the following makefile but I get error when I compile it as: No such file or directory found.
Here is the makefile I am trying to execute:
P.S. I am trying to execute this on Linux and windows both but same error I get on both of them.

```
CC = gcc
#LFLAG = 
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O4 -DWMOPS=0 -D__MSDOS__

# Objects
OBJ =  coder.o agc2.o autocorr.o az_isp.o bits.o c2t64fx.o c4t64fx.o cod_main.o \
    convolve.o cor_h_x.o d2t64fx.o d4t64fx.o decim54.o dec_main.o deemph.o \
    dtx.o d_gain2.o gpclip.o g_pitch.o hp6k.o hp7k.o hp50.o hp400.o hp_wsp.o \
    int_lpc.o isfextrp.o isp_az.o isp_isf.o lagconc.o lag_wind.o levinson.o \
    lp_dec2.o math_op.o ph_disp.o pitch_f4.o pit_shrp.o pred_lt4.o preemph.o \
    p_med_ol.o qisf_ns.o qpisf_2s.o q_gain2.o q_pulse.o random.o residu.o \
    scale.o syn_filt.o updt_tar.o util.o voicefac.o wb_vad.o weight_a.o \
    basicop2.o count.o log2.o oper_32b.o homing.o \

DOBJ =  decoder.o agc2.o autocorr.o az_isp.o bits.o c2t64fx.o c4t64fx.o cod_main.o \
    convolve.o cor_h_x.o d2t64fx.o d4t64fx.o decim54.o dec_main.o deemph.o \
    dtx.o d_gain2.o gpclip.o g_pitch.o hp6k.o hp7k.o hp50.o hp400.o hp_wsp.o \
    int_lpc.o isfextrp.o isp_az.o isp_isf.o lagconc.o lag_wind.o levinson.o \
    lp_dec2.o math_op.o ph_disp.o pitch_f4.o pit_shrp.o pred_lt4.o preemph.o \
    p_med_ol.o qisf_ns.o qpisf_2s.o q_gain2.o q_pulse.o random.o residu.o \
    scale.o syn_filt.o updt_tar.o util.o voicefac.o wb_vad.o weight_a.o \
    basicop2.o count.o log2.o oper_32b.o homing.o \

# Implicit Rules
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c  $<

all:    coder decoder

# Explicit Rules
coder:    $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o coder $(OBJ)
decoder:  $(DOBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o decoder $(DOBJ)

# Individual File Dependencies

basicop2.o: typedef.h basic_op.h count.h
count.o:    typedef.h count.h
log2.o:     log2.h typedef.h basic_op.h count.h log2_tab.h
oper_32b.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h count.h
autocorr.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h acelp_fx.h count.h
az_isp.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h count.h
bits.o:     typedef.h basic_op.h cnst_fx.h bits_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h dtx_fx.h
c2t64fx.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h acelp_fx.h count.h cnst_fx.h
c4t64fx.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h acelp_fx.h count.h cnst_fx.h q_pulse_fx.h
cod_main.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h math_op.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h \
    cod_main_fx.h bits_fx.h count.h
convolve.o: typedef.h basic_op.h count.h
cor_h_x.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h count.h
d2t64fx.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h cnst_fx.h
d4t64fx.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h cnst_fx.h q_pulse_fx.h
decim54.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h acelp_fx.h count.h cnst_fx.h
dec_main.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h dec_main_fx.h  bits_fx.h  count.h  math_op.h 
deemph.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h count.h
dtx.o:      typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h math_op.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h bits_fx.h dtx_fx.h count.h log2.h
d_gain2.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h math_op.h log2.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
gpclip.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
g_pitch.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h count.h 
homing.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h cnst_fx.h bits_fx.h
hp400.o:    typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
hp50.o:     typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
hp6k.o:     typedef.h basic_op.h acelp_fx.h count.h cnst_fx.h 
hp_wsp.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
int_lpc.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
isfextrp.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
isp_az.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h count.h cnst_fx.h 
isp_isf.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
lagconc.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h 
lag_wind.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h 
levinson.o: typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
lp_dec2.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h cnst_fx.h 
math_op.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h count.h 
ph_disp.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
pitch_f4.o: typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h acelp_fx.h cnst_fx.h count.h 
pit_shrp.o: typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
pred_lt4.o: typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
preemph.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
p_med_ol.o: typedef.h basic_op.h acelp_fx.h oper_32b.h count.h math_op.h 
qisf_ns.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
qpisf_2s.o: typedef.h basic_op.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
q_gain2.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h oper_32b.h math_op.h count.h log2.h acelp_fx.h 
q_pulse.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h count.h q_pulse_fx.h 
random.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
residu.o:   typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
scale.o:    typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
syn_filt.o: typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h count.h cnst_fx.h 
updt_tar.o: typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
util.o:     typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
voicefac.o: typedef.h basic_op.h math_op.h count.h 
wb_vad.o:   cnst_fx.h wb_vad_fx.h typedef.h basic_op.h count.h math_op.h wb_vad_c_fx.h 
weight_a.o: typedef.h basic_op.h count.h 
agc2.o:     cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h typedef.h basic_op.h count.h math_op.h 
hp7k.o:     typedef.h basic_op.h cnst_fx.h acelp_fx.h count.h 
decoder.o:  typedef.h basic_op.h acelp_fx.h cnst_fx.h main.h bits_fx.h dtx_fx.h count.h 
coder.o:    typedef.h basic_op.h acelp_fx.h cnst_fx.h cod_main_fx.h bits_fx.h   count.h cod_main_fx.h
```

THE Exact ERROR I am getting is this:

```
make -f makefile.gcc
gcc -Wall -g -O4 -DWMOPS=0 -D__MSDOS__ -o coder coder.o agc2.o autocorr.o az_isp.o bits.o c2t64fx.o c4t64fx.o cod_main.o convolve.o cor_h_x.o d2t64fx.o d4t64fx.o decim54.o dec_main.o deemph.o dtx.o d_gain2.o gpclip.o g_pitch.o hp6k.o hp7k.o hp50.o hp400.o hp_wsp.o int_lpc.o isfextrp.o isp_az.o isp_isf.o lagconc.o lag_wind.o levinson.o lp_dec2.o math_op.o ph_disp.o pitch_f4.o pit_shrp.o pred_lt4.o preemph.o p_med_ol.o qisf_ns.o qpisf_2s.o q_gain2.o q_pulse.o random.o residu.o scale.o syn_filt.o updt_tar.o util.o voicefac.o wb_vad.o weight_a.o basicop2.o count.o log2.o oper_32b.o homing.o 
gcc: error: coder.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: agc2.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: autocorr.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: az_isp.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: bits.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: c2t64fx.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: c4t64fx.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: cod_main.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: convolve.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: cor_h_x.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: d2t64fx.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: d4t64fx.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: decim54.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: dec_main.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: deemph.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: dtx.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: d_gain2.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gpclip.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: g_pitch.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: hp6k.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: hp7k.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: hp50.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: hp400.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: hp_wsp.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: int_lpc.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: isfextrp.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: isp_az.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: isp_isf.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: lagconc.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: lag_wind.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: levinson.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: lp_dec2.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ph_disp.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: pitch_f4.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: pit_shrp.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: pred_lt4.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: preemph.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: p_med_ol.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: qisf_ns.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: qpisf_2s.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: q_gain2.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: q_pulse.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: random.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: residu.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: scale.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: syn_filt.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: updt_tar.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: util.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: voicefac.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: wb_vad.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: weight_a.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: homing.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [coder] Error 1
```

Comment: What's the *actual* error? I don't see any references to a literal `filename` in your Makefile.

Comment: do you want `$@` before `$<` in the implicit rules? You can check if the .o files are building, because they should be in your working directory.

Comment: I Updated the question withactual error I am getting

Comment: @dmedime it is not able to build any .o files also . I dont understand where it is going wrong

Comment: It's probably not able to find the .c files. Are there .c files in the same directory, or did you set VPATH or vpath?

Comment: You should check into automatic dependency generation.

Comment: c files are there in the same directory but it seems it is not able to compile the c files to .o files.

Comment: This makefile looks OK to me.  Personally I would add an explicit `-o $@` to the `.c.o` suffix rule, but I don't think that should be necessary.  Since this makefile looks correct there's something about your environment that you're not accurately describing.  If you run `make -d`, where does `make` find the various object files like `coder.o`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't find the object files, because they are not built. And the object files are not built, because the sources are in a different directory (e.g. src) or make doesn't see them for some other reason.

---

I investigated this a bit more with [`--debug`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html)

```
make --debug=v -f makefile.gcc
```

and get

> Reading makefiles...
>   Reading makefile `makefile.gcc'...
>   Updating goal targets....
>   Considering target file `all'.
>   File `all' does not exist.
>   Considering target file `coder'.
>   File `coder' does not exist.
>   Considering target file `coder.o'.
>   File `coder.o' does not exist.
>   Considering target file `typedef.h'.
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `typedef.h'.
>   No need to remake target `typedef.h'.
>   Considering target file `basic_op.h'.
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `basic_op.h'.
>   No need to remake target `basic_op.h'.
>   ...
>   Considering target file `count.h'.
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `count.h'.
>   No need to remake target `count.h'.
>   Pruning file `cod_main_fx.h'.
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `coder.o'.
>   Must remake target `coder.o'.
>   Successfully remade target file `coder.o'.
>   Considering target file `agc2.o'.
>   File `agc2.o' does not exist.
>   Pruning file `cnst_fx.h'.
>   Pruning file `acelp_fx.h'.
>   Pruning file `typedef.h'.
>   Pruning file `basic_op.h'.
>   ...
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `homing.o'.
>   Must remake target `homing.o'.
>   Successfully remade target file `homing.o'.
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `coder'.
>   Must remake target `coder'.
>   gcc -Wall -g -O4 -DWMOPS=0 -D__MSDOS__ -o coder coder.o agc2.o autocorr.o ...
>   gcc: error: coder.o: No such file or directory
>   gcc: error: agc2.o: No such file or directory
>   gcc: error: autocorr.o: No such file or directory

Because of the header file dependencies, make thinks it has properly remade the object file targets, even though it doesn't see the source files.

If you provide a source file (even an empty one), the output looks a little bit different

> ...
>   Finished prerequisites of target file `coder.o'.
>   Must remake target `coder.o'.
>   gcc -Wall -g -O4 -DWMOPS=0 -D__MSDOS__  -c  coder.c
>   Successfully remade target file `coder.o'.
>   Considering target file `agc2.o'.
>   File `agc2.o' does not exist.
>   Pruning file `cnst_fx.h'.
>   ...

Here you can see, how make checks all the prerequisites and then rebuilds the object file, using the implicit rule given in the makefile.

You can avoid make's confusion, by listing the source file as a dependency explicitly, e.g.

```
coder.o: coder.c
```

Make will then complain about the missing source file without invoking the link command

> make: *** No rule to make target `coder.c', needed by `coder.o'.  Stop.

Comment: I don't see how this could be true.  The object files are listed as prerequisites of the target according to this makefile; therefore if make can't find them or build them it will report an error, it won't try to build the target.

Comment: Just try and see for yourself. Create a directory with just the makefile and needed header files and run make. You will see exactly OP's (gcc's) error message.

Comment: I also debugged it ans it seems there is problem in c file which is not able to make the object file. Thank you for you time and help.